# Is the concept of Safek D'oraisa l'chumra relevant when dealing with a machlokes d'oraisa / d'rabbanan?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, derabanan, safek, deorayta

There are cases where Rishonim disagree as to whether a particular law is from the Torah or a Rabbinical decree. In such cases, must one be strict due to the possible violation of a Torah prohibition?

Comment: See BY YD 98 IINM

Comment: @DoubleAA is that Beis Yosef on Yoreh Deah 98?

Comment: Yes. [][][][][][]